# Let $f$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that the Fourier transform of $f$ exists almost everywhere. Is $f\in L^1 \cup L^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

Problem: Let $f$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that the Fourier transform of $f$ exist almost everywhere. Is $f\in L^1 \cup L^2$ ?

My opinion: We know that if $f\in L^1\cup L^2$, then the Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ exist a.e., but if for a continuous function $f$, $\hat{f}$ exist a.e., then can we say that $f\in L^1 \cup L^2$?

More precisely, what is the necessary condition to define the Fourier transformation in the classical sense (not the distributional sense)?

Comment: You need $f \in L^1$ for the integral $\hat{f}(\xi)$ to converge absolutely for all $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$. But there are many distributions whose Fourier transforms are functions. For example, any compactly supported distribution has a smooth Fourier transform.

Comment: IF integration is in the sense of Lebesgue, then at least $f\in L_1$. if $f$ is locally integrable and $\lim_{A\rightarrow\infty}\int^A_{-A}e^{-2\pi i xt}f(x)\,dx$ exists a.s. for all $t$, then $f\in L_2$.